# enable epel-release on RHEL 7

Tags: rhel7, epel

I have RHEL 7 Virtual machine , where I need to enable epel-release using  Red Hat Subscription Manager?

Any idea how to enable a epel repository using Red Hat Subscription Manager?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot enable EPEL through Subscription Manager (without first adding the required repo information to `/etc/yum.repos.d/`).

See [How to use Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL)?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3358)